# Gson error when enabling proguard

Tags: android, gson, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to enable proguard in my project but my class keeps getting obfuscated by the proguard and I got this message:

```
 Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 4313
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.response.LoginResponse
                                                                     for method AccountsEndPoint.login
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:738)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
                                                                     at $Proxy1.login(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.myapp.myapp.presentation.activities.LoginActivity.a(LoginActivity.java:211)
                                                                     at com.myapp.myapp.presentation.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:97)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.myapp.myapp.data.b.a.a declares multiple JSON fields named a
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:64)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:736)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169) 
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170) 
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813) 
                                                                     at $Proxy1.login(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at com.myapp.myapp.presentation.activities.LoginActivity.a(LoginActivity.java:211) 
                                                                     at com.myapp.myapp.presentation.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:97) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I'm using `@SerializedName` annotation in my models also I'm adding to my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.request.** { *;}
-keep class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.response.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you come across this error, check if you:

1 - Added @SerializedName to your model's attributes. (This helps GSON to find the real name)

2 - Add this configuration to your proguard file:

```
###GSON
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
-keep class com.myapp.data.remote.request.** { *; } # <--- Add your models package here
```

3- If you keep getting this error check if ALL your models are using the @SerializedName and are in the package included in above rule

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add proguard for gson from the [following link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg). It contains this:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can try to keep the fields in your class with:

```
-keep class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.request.** { <fields>; }
-keep class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.response.** { <fields>; }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer adding how to keep the fields.

Comment: Tryied your answer also I tryied to use this: -keepclassmembers class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.request.** { <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.myapp.data.remote.response.** { <fields>; }

Answer (score 0):

Proguard obfuscates your class, fields and method names So that it cannot be deserialized.

First try using `@SerializedName` annotation in all the fields of your model classes.

eg.

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
```

Also use proper proguard settings as mentioned by @ישו אוהב אותך.

If any of these couldn't solve your problem, the last resort would be to disable the proguard.

Set `minifyEnabled false` in the file `build.gradle`

Comment: Like I said in my question i'm using @SerializedName also trying to keep my class using proguard rules.